# DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a byte, string or number first. | Google Cloud Memory Store (Managed Redis)

Tags: python, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm trying to put a simple python dictionary  as a value `{"roundType":"ROUND_OFF","roundUpto":2}` in Cloud Memory Store.

for ex. `MyConfig` is the **key** and its **value** as `{"roundType":"ROUND_OFF","roundUpto":2}`.

Here is my generic handler to set the data.

```
def set(key, value):
    import redis
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    return r.set(key, value)
```

But it gives the error as `DataError: Invalid input of type: 'dict'. Convert to a byte, string or number first.`

Here I made my generic set method to put the data, I'm thinking about to do some operations before putting the value to avoid such errors, What operations must be performed on the value or ideal way to put the data into Redis.

P.S. Most of the time data would be either of String, Number, List, Dictionary or Json.

Comment: What about the list & json!